# Pass Object From One Class To Other Class

Tags: ios

[image]

This is the structure which I am following. In class two, I have created `CALayer` object. When the user touches it, I need to pass that `CALayer` object from the first class two to the second class two. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is.  Just declare the property in your class, synthesize it and assign it when necessary.

Comment: Declare your object in .h file (your view controller) and give "@property" and "@synthesize" in proper way, so this object you can detect any where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard then use `segue` to display destination viewController and set destination viewController's `CALayer` object like this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setMyCALayerObject:currentCALayerObject];
}
```

You need to have a `CALayer` object `myCALayerObject` in destination viewController to set to current `CALayer` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prepareForSegue` to send messages to the `destinationViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [[segue destinationViewController] myMessage:myArgument];
}
```